# Free monoidal category out of multicategory

Tags: category-theory, categorical-logic

There's a known adjoint pair $Cat \rightarrow MonCat \dashv MonCat \rightarrow Cat$.
[See here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category#Free_strict_monoidal_category)

The question is: is there a similar construction $Multicat \rightarrow MonCat \dashv MonCat \rightarrow Multicat$ ?

---

My idea for the forgetful functor $U:MonCat \rightarrow Multicat$ was to send a monoidal category to a new category with the same objects and with homsets that remain the same if the codomain "has no tensors", and are mapped to the emptyset otherwise ---i.e: if the codomain "has tensors".

By "has no tensors" I mean that it's not of the form $a\otimes b$ nor $1$: it's "a single object". I'm not sure one can say this and thus why I'm asking. Maybe in some subclass of monoidal categories?

---

This would intuitively give a "stronger" free monoidal category in the sense that we could have morphisms between lists of different sizes. We would do this by having lists of multimorphisms, one for each object in the list of codomains $a_1\otimes a_2 \otimes\dots\otimes a_n$. (And this is what the free functor would do.)

This construction is motivated by the notion of category of contexts.

---

Any idea? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: That is not the right way to define the multicategory associated with a monoidal category. The right way to define $U(C)$ is to let its objects be those of $C$ and the multimorphisms from a finite (possibly empty) list $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n$ to $B$ be the morphisms from $A_1 \otimes A_2 \otimes ... \otimes A_n$ to $B$ in $C$ (using the unit object $1$ for the "empty tensor product" if $n=0$).

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang right! that's trivial to do and feels way more appropriate for a forgetful functor morally now that you say it, thanks! Is the construction I gave after it the left adjoint to this functor? (I barely sketched the idea but I hope it's clear.)

Comment: For a multicategory $M$, the free monoidal category on $M$ should have its objects as the finite lists of objects of $M$ and the morphisms $(A_1, A_2, ..., A_m) \to (B_1, B_2, ..., B_n)$ consisting of a decomposition $m_1 + m_2 + ... + m_n$ of $m$ as a sum of $n$ nonnegative integers (thus dividing the domain into $n$ sublists) and a multimorphism from the $i$th sublist to $B_i$ for $i=1, 2, ..., n$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang: could you post this as an answer, so that it doesn't remain resolved in the comments? An explicit reference for the adjointness is Theorem 7.2 of Hermida's [Representable Multicategories](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870899918777).